# "質問の削除" に伴って回答が削除された場合のバナー表示を改善して欲しい

Tags: 機能の要求

投稿が削除された際、通常は「誰が or どんな理由で」「いつ」削除したかの情報がバナーとして表示されます。
(削除された投稿を表示するには一定の信用度が必要です)

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

しかし、"質問の削除に伴って" 回答が削除された場合には、理由に当たる説明が現状では表示されません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

同じページ上で質問の削除に対して説明が表示されているとはいえ、回答に対しても詳しい説明が表示された方がより親切ではないかと思います。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2021-10 現在、"質問の削除" に伴って回答が削除された場合のバナーメッセージが変更されたようです。
(別途、翻訳が必要ですね)

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 翻訳を[Traducir](https://ja.traducir.win/strings/15392)に入力いたしました。反映まで少しお待ちください。